# Reclassify raster with for loop and seq

Tags: r, for-loop, raster, seq

I wand to reclassify a raster with a `for loop` based on `seq` with `reclassify function` from `raster package`, the output of the following code is empty, I don't understand why.

```
#create a random raster
sam <- sample(seq(0,1,0.01), 1000*1000, replace = TRUE)
r1 <- raster(nrows = 1000, ncols = 1000, vals = sam)

#create the scale for reclassify
scale <- seq(0,1,0.2)

#the for loop
cl_r <- for (i in 1:length(scale)){
  reclassify(r1, c(scale[i], scale[i+1], scale[i+1]))
}
```

The output:

```
> cl_r
NULL
```

I suppose that `scale[i+1]` is understandable by R as `scale[1+1]` works.

Comment: Can you edit your question to state what are you trying to achieve? I can't figure that out, but what you are proposing does not seem to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I deduce that you have numbers between 0 and 1 and would like to bin these in groups of 0.2 (0 to 0.2, 0.2 to 0.4, etc). If so, there is a number of ways to do that.

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
#values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
values(r) <- seq(0.01, 1, .01)
```

The simplest approach is to use `cut`

```
x <- cut(r, seq(0,1,.2))
```

You can use reclassify like this

```
m <- cbind(seq(0,.8,.2), seq(0.2,1,.2), 1:5)
y <- reclassify(r, m)
```

Or an algebraic approach

```
z <- ceiling(r * 5)
```

Also if you are going to loop over `scale` like that, note that you get `NA` at the end.

```
scale <- seq(0,1,0.2)
for (i in 1:length(scale)) { 
    cat(scale[i], "-", scale[i+1], "\n")
}
#0 - 0.2 
#0.2 - 0.4 
#0.4 - 0.6 
#0.6 - 0.8 
#0.8 - 1 
#1 - NA
```

It would be cleaner to do

```
for (i in 2:length(scale)) { 
    cat(scale[i-1], "-", scale[i], "\n")
}
#0 - 0.2 
#0.2 - 0.4 
#0.4 - 0.6 
#0.6 - 0.8 
#0.8 - 1
```

And presumably what you intended was

```
rc <- r
for (i in 2:length(seq(0,1,0.2))) {
     rc <- reclassify(rc, cbind(scale[i-1], scale[i], scale[i])) 
}
rc
```

Comment: Hi! You guess right, I have numbers between 0 and 1. In fact the for loop didn't work in this case (the aim was mainly to avoid to make by hand a reclassify table and to make it through seq). The solution you propose with cut ````x <- cut(r, seq(0,1,.2))```` perfectly works ! Thank you !